# MixItUp animation with 'overflow: hidden' parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, mixitup

I have problems with the [MixItUp jQuery addon](https://mixitup.kunkalabs.com)

When I initialize a MixItUp container inside a `overflow: hidden` parent, I have animation problems on init and filtering.

With `overflow: hidden` there is another animation effect like [this](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/)

You can see an example on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7qbwe8mn/)

When you remove the `overflow: hidden` in the jsfiddle example, it is working as expected.

In my project, the MixItUp is inside the iDangerous swiper, so I can’t remove the 'oveflow: hidden', because it is necessary.

Is there a way to solve this problem, with css or script?

HTML:

```
<div id="Container">
    <div id="Container2">
        <div class="mix"></div>
        <div class="mix"></div>
        <div class="mix"></div>
        <div class="mix"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="filter" data-filter="all">All</div>
<div class="filter" data-filter="none">None</div>
```

CSS:

```
#Container {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.mix {
    background: black;
    display: none;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(function () {

    $('#Container').mixItUp({
        animation: {
            effects: 'fade translateZ(-360px) stagger(34ms)'
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Improved some formatting and urls

Comment: @FabioAntunes code in question is still required. Please add a closevote. Editing was optional.

Comment: @JanDvorak in that case I added the jsfiddle code, instead of voting to close a question that is quite reasonable. It's always easier to close questions than help new users.

Comment: That works, too. It seems answerable now - unless people find the question unclear anyways.

Comment: Thanks for your help, and sorry for the wrong question formatting. Can't you see the difference with the animation? With "overflow: hidden", there is a additional "slide up" animation.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

Solution:
Set a height to the #Container